# Android rating bar star is not aligned properly when applying android:progressTint

Tags: android, kotlin, ratingbar

I'm trying to implement a rating bar. But when changing the color of the star it shows another star behind it.

Here is my XML and also picture is attached

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressTint="#ffdf00"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: image of my ratingbar implementation]

Comment: That's interesting... I tried it on my end, and it's aligned properly (with exactly the same code you have). Perhaps try rebuilding the project (**Build** >> **Rebuild Project**)?

Comment: @DavidLee yeah I also tried and it's aligned properly

Comment: i tried Build >> Rebuild Project , Invalidate cache and restart but no luck. My android version is oreo(8.0)

Comment: Don't think if it will be useful but try using `app:progressTint` instead of `android:progressTint`

Comment: app:progressTint not working. I think it's some oter problem. facing this issue only in android 8.0